# Why Do Support Vector Machines Require 3 Support Vectors?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, optimization, supervised-learning

Whenever I see a visualization of support vector machines, the separating hyperplane always has three support vectors. I don't understand why it isn't two. Given that the best separating hyperplane only has to maximize the size of its margins from the nearest points of each class, I would think that only two support vectors, one from class A, and one from class B, would be required. Can anyone explain to me why this is not the case?